# Android Application is unexpectedly stopped error when button is clicked

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Hi there I'm totally new to Android development and I'm working in my android application 
my application includes a forum where users can post, comment and have their discussion there....
So I'm working in the interface but I get error when I click on the button I directs me to the signup page 
can somebody please help me with this error

this is the code of the mainuserinterface.java for the mainuserinterface.xml file where the button resides. and the signupform.class is the java file for the next activity triggered when the button is clicked

the error I receive is the application is unexpectedly stopped..
Hope I make it clear for you guys

```
package com.mohammed.watzIslam;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class mainuserinterface extends Activity  {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainuserinterface);

// this is the button where I receive errors when I click 
Button forum = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next); 

forum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent (view.getContext(), signupform.class);
        startActivityForResult (myIntent, 0);

    }
});

 //these two button still not directing to any next activity yet
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next); 

forum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view){
        Intent myIntent1 = new Intent (view.getContext(), signupform.class);
        startActivityForResult (myIntent1, 0);

    }
});
Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next); 

forum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view){
        Intent myIntent2 = new Intent (view.getContext(), signupform.class);
        startActivityForResult (myIntent2, 0);

    }
});
}
}
```

Comment: can you please upload error log and code of your AndroidManifest.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

Run 'adb logcat' to see the Exception that is causing the failure and the stack trace.

Generally I have seen this sort of issue in two cases:
- signupform is not listed as an activity in AndroidManifest.xml
- there is some Exception occurring in signupform.onCreate()

Either way, 'adb logcat' should give you some idea of the problem.  If you have logcat output and still have a question, please edit your question and add the exception info and stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Check you Manifest file and declare the activity if you haven't done.. When we are new to android many times we forget to declare our activty in manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many things that can be reason for your problem.

- you should relpace  `View.getContect` to `mainuserinterface.this`
- check your `manifest Entry` have you added new class activity ?